# Pusher not able to establish connection

Tags: ruby, stream, pusher

I'm trying to connect to the Liquid exchange's Stream API with pusher. [Documentation here](https://developers.liquid.com/?ruby#authenticated)

I have constructed a function that is in line with the Pusher library's documentation. [Link to that here](https://github.com/pusher-community/pusher-websocket-ruby#installation)
My current code looks like this:

```rb
require 'pusher-client'
channels_client = PusherClient::Socket.new('LIQUID', {
      ws_host: 'tap.liquid.com'
  })
```

and running that gives me an error message of:

> D, [2019-08-20Txx:xx:xx.xxxxxx #xxxxx] DEBUG -- : Binding
>   pusher:connection_established to pusher_global_channel
>
> D, [2019-08-20Txx:xx:xx.xxxxxx #xxxxx] DEBUG -- : Binding
>   pusher:connection_disconnected to pusher_global_channel
>
> D, [2019-08-20Txx:xx:xx.xxxxxx #xxxxx] DEBUG -- : Binding pusher:error
>   to pusher_global_channel
>
> D, [2019-08-20Txx:xx:xx.xxxxxx #xxxxx] DEBUG -- : Binding pusher:ping
>   to pusher_global_channel

If I try to run this after the first command:

```rb
channels_client.connect
```

...it refuses to connect.

> C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pusher-client-0.6.2/lib/pusher-client/websocket.rb:17:in
>   `initialize': No connection could be made because the target machine
>   actively refused it. - connect(2) for "tap.liquid.com" port 80
>   (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from tcpsocket.new (Ruby https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/socket/rdoc/TCPSocket.html) in websocket line 17: https://github.com/pusher-community/pusher-websocket-ruby/blob/master/lib/pusher-client/websocket.rb

ws_host tap.liquid.com 80 seems to be invalid, https://pusher.com/docs/channels/library_auth_reference/pusher-websockets-protocol

I have tried using a secure connection, at least in the browser and got a 404 for ws and invalid request, which is good in this case, for https (https://tap.liquid.com/).

You need to configure ssl in the client configuration, but the pusher-client gem as well as one other I have found are pretty old. Maybe it is wise to switch to a more up-to-date library like https://github.com/pusher/pusher-http-ruby/blob/master/README.md

The example contains an option for activated SSL.